# How can I have two rows in my table that span multiple columns, while still being compatible with bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm using bootstrap with my web application.  I'm trying to get a table design layout to work while still being able to use bootstrap's `table-striped` class.  Currently I'm using the following:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Started</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>
         <div>John Doe</div>
         <div>12 Sales Total; 4 March, 3 April, 12 July, 14 August</div>
      </td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>Feb. 12th 2010</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, I'm wanting the `12 Sales Total; 4 March, 3 April, 12 July, 14 August` of the table to appear below `John Doe      Sales       Feb. 12th 2010` and not wrap within the column it's in now.  If I use two separate `<tr>` elements to get the layout to work then the `table-striped` no longer works properly.

**Edit:**

So here is the current setup.  This gets what I want except for the issue where the text on the div doesn't span the other columns, and just wraps within the column it's currently in. https://jsfiddle.net/AkT6R/

I've tried something earlier that was mentioned in a submitted answer by @Bryce, but this isn't compatible with Bootstrap it seems. https://jsfiddle.net/AkT6R/1/

Comment: You can have a <td> element span across multiple columns with the colspan attribute. Similarly you can use the rowspan attribute to span multiple rows. You won't be able to make 1 div inside a <td> span multiple columns without some very clever CSS. Your best bet is to alter the cell that has the name and move the sales totals to a new row with the colspan set to 4.

Comment: Please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @AlexW, sorry updated the post with them.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Like so. You need rowspan plus colspan:

```
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Started</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>6</td>
      <td>
         <div>John Doe</div>
      </td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>Feb. 12th 2010</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3>
         <div>12 Sales Total; 4 March, 3 April, 12 July, 14 August</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See it in action at https://jsfiddle.net/brycenesbitt/QJ4m5/2/

---

Then for your CSS problem.  Right click and "Inspect element" in Chrome.  Your background color comes from `bootstrap.min.css`.  This applies a color to even and odd rows:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th
{
background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Fiddle it appropriately for your double sized rows:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(4n+1)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(4n+2)>td
{    background-color: #ff10ff;
}
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(4n+3)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(4n+4)>td
{    background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

Done.

Comment: I've tried something similar to this, but using this method doesn't seem to work with Bootstrap.

Comment: Start by accepting a solution here if you like, forking the fiddle above, and then you can reformulate a question targeted to bootstrap.  Structurally the rowspan/colspan solution is 100% correct, now your challenge apparently lies with bootstrap.

Comment: Based on your edit, I added the CSS solution.  Don't resist the row/colspan approach: it really is the best way forward.

Answer (score 3):

Use the colspan tag attribute.

```
<td colspan="2">
```

or

`<td colspan="4">`

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

Comment: This was my first thought too. I don't know if this is what he's looking for though. It seems like he wants his nested div to span the columns, but still have the columns otherwise.

Comment: I was wondering about that, too, but thought I would answer the possible and let him clarify his request if necessary